# Cast vector data of unique_ptr to pointer to const pointer

Tags: c++, casting, stdvector, unique-ptr, std

I have a `std::vector` of `std::unique_ptr` and I want to call a function from an API that takes a pointer to const pointer. Would it be correct to cast its `data()` to that type?

This example program seems to work in GCC:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A
{
public:
    A(int n) : n(n) {}
    int n;
};

int main()
{
    const int num = 3;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> v;
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        v.push_back(std::make_unique<A>(i));
    }
    auto vPtr = (A * const *) v.data();
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        std::cout << vPtr[i]->n << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Does the standard guarantee that the layout of `std::unique_ptr` is just a pointer, and thus this is safe to do?

Comment: The standard guarantees that this is **not** safe to do.  When I've run into this situation, I've built another (temporary) vector holding raw pointers constructed from the `v[i].get()` of the other vector and it's owning smart pointers .

Comment: _"Does the standard guarantee that the layout of `std::unique_ptr` is just a pointer?"_ Not all. Don't forget that a unique pointer has a deleter subobject. Even though stateless deleters may be optimized to occupy no storage, this is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Eljay I resorted to that too... Somewhat inconvenient, if at least C++ had variable-length arrays I could do it at the point where I call the function without heap allocation, but yes I'll just have to keep the extra vector.

Comment: If the vector has a maximum possible size, you could use an array of that maximum size.  (Presuming such size isn't in danger of blowing the stack on your platform.)  If there is no known maximum size, then shadow vector is the best you can do, with a `shadow.reserve(v.size())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is an aliasing violation. A `std::unique_ptr` is not a raw pointer.

"seems to work in GCC" is not safe in C++. You code has undefined behaviour, and "seems to work" is the *worst* symptom, because it can suddenly become "breaks in the most inopportune way" with no notice.

Comment: OP's code could be well-defined but makes the assumption that `std::unique_ptr` is standard-layout. This is not guaranteed by the standard so it isn't safe assumption, but it's also not correct to call it a strict aliasing violation with no asterisk.

Comment: @JanSchultke you still have to respect aliasing with the cast, which is not the case here, we are adding `const`

Comment: C-style casts also act as a `const_cast`, so this is fine. Adding a `const` implicitly here wouldn't be allowed because of const-correctness, but doing so via cast is allowed. The const doesn't have any impact on OP's code anyway and doesn't make it any more or less UB. It all boils down to whether `std::unique_ptr` is standard-layout.

Comment: Standard layout lets you `reinterpret_cast` without violating aliasing, but it doesn't let you `const_cast` without aliasing

Comment: Why do you think that the added `const` is relevant here? Adding `const` unnecessarily cannot violate strict aliasing and is always safe.

Comment: @JanSchultke: It very much depends on where in the type `const` is added.  The question is not proposing to add it at the top level, where it would be safe.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, I have mentioned const-correctness issues already, but it's also completely irrelevant to OP's question because all access takes place to the bottom level object where adding `const` unnecessarily is safe.

Comment: @JanSchultke adding const *isn't* irrelevant to strict aliasing. Which is secondary to also assuming that `std::unique_ptr` is standard layout

Comment: @Caleth two similar types can alias each other, and the cv-qualified version of one type is similar to that of the unqualified version. `const`ness is thus irrelevant. If you were right, then adding or removing `const` would break strict aliasing and this would obviously make 99% of C++ code UB.

Comment: @JanSchultke: `T const*` is similar to `T*`, but `std::unique_ptr<T const>` is NOT similar to `std::unique_ptr<T>`.  There's a conversion, but *aliasing* is prohibited.

Comment: @BenVoigt I know. My point was that if `std::unique_ptr<T>` stores a `T*` as its first member and is standard-layout, then the aliasing would be allowed due to pointer-interconvertibility. Of course, this layout is not guaranteed by the standard, but it is possible in principle. With such layout, `const` would be irrelevant to strict aliasing.

Comment: If it were standard-layout (but it's not) then pointer-interconvertibility would then allow aliasing `std::unique_ptr<T>` with `T*` but still not with `std::unique_ptr<const T>`

Comment: @JanSchultke By my reading of standard layout, `reinterpret_cast`ing then `const_cast`ing `std::unique_ptr<T>` as `T const *` is an aliasing violation, even if the reinterpret cast is ok

Comment: If the `std::unique_ptr<T>` is standard-layout and it contains a `T*` as its first member, then the `reinterpret_cast<T*>` is perfectly fine. Adding or removing `const` is never a strict aliasing violation; only modifying a const object is UB (of a different kind).

Comment: @JanSchultke and even if `std::unique_ptr<T>` is standard layout, `reinterpret_cast`ing a `std::unique_ptr<T>*` to a `T**` and indexing it is always UB, which is the operation asked about in the question

Comment: I'm not so sure if it would be a strict aliasing violation in that scenario since all access in C++ still takes place through scalar types; so the array in itself is not the type that is used to access the object. However, you would probably run into UB as the result of pointer arithmetic on the wrong type. I'm just trying to point out that there is a bit of nuance and which UB you run into isn't 100% clear, or whether there even is UB if `std::unique_ptr` is implemented favorably.

Comment: I'm not saying adding const always makes something an aliasing violation, but when you are in the very small defined `reinterpret_cast` zone, going anywhere extra can be.